# Need more information about adServer and how to create my owen adServer?

Tags: ads, advertisement-server

I need to find books, websites or whatever to learn about AdServer and AdServing, because I need to develop my own AdServer.
I've already done a lot of searching, but I didn't find something interesting.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: You need to be more precise. Do you need an Ad server to serve some ads in your own website as an independent publisher, or do you need a solution to create/deploy an Ad server as a service?

Comment: Thank you for your response what i need is to find a book , website tutoriel ... that explain how to create/deploy an mobile(iphone android mobile app) Ad Server as a service.

Comment: if you find some links please share them with us.

Answer (score 3):

First off, "Mobile Ad Servers" today don't have clear specs and most of them are classic ad servers "recalibrated", and I can't think of a worth-talking-about open source mobile ad server.

I think you should familiarize yourself with how classic ad servers work and then you can go beyond. I've done my own research once and the best resources I've found so far are:

- Some open source Ad Servers that you can learn from (depending on your preferred programming platform, the most stable one that I can think of is [OpenX](http://www.openx.com))
- This link: [The Interactive Advertising Bureau](http://www.iab.net/about_the_iab), which is the organism behind 86% of served online advertising in the US. Its mission is normalizing the business specs behind the online advertising industry and you can learn a lot from their website.

Informations related to this field are sensitive, which explains the lack of true answers for your question. Good luck :-)